# Could not find 'adb.exe' in ......?

Tags: python-3.x, adb, appium

**How to fix Could not find 'adb.exe'?**

I think my question is one of the most asked and answered question of the Android world. I read and tried them all.

- I checked and update my environment variables.
- I desinstalled and reinstalled ANdroid Studio
- I copied pasted adb in all possible folders:
      C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk 
      C:\Program Files\Android
      C:\Program Files\Android\tools 
      C:\Program Files\Android\platform-tools

In fact I spent all the day by searching, reading and testing all the solution possible.

And nothing fixed my problem. So I really need your help.

I am newbie and I want to share my experience. Here is my code:

```
from appium import webdriver
import unittest

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Instagram(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName']='Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion']='6.0'
        desired_caps['deviceName']='S6S5IN3G'
        desired_caps['noReset']='true'
        desired_caps['appPackage']='com.instagram'
        desired_caps['appActivity']='com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity'

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_scrap_email(self):
        search_button = self.driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//android.widget.ImageView[@bounds='[126,800][162,836]']"))
        search_button.click()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.Testloader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Instagram)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite)
```

This is the errors:

> Testing started at 01:00 ...
>   C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2019.1.3\helpers\pycharm_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target mybot_instagram.Instagram.test_scrap_email Launching unittests with
>   arguments python -m unittest
>   mybot_instagram.Instagram.test_scrap_email in
>   C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram
>
> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py",
>   line 59, in testPartExecutor
>       yield   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py",
>   line 624, in run
>       self.setUp()   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\mybot_instagram.py", line 17,
>   in setUp
>       self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)   File
>   "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py",
>   line 144, in **init**
>       proxy   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py",
>   line 219, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File
>   "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown
>   server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in ["C:\Program
>   Files\Android\platform-tools\platform-tools\adb.exe","C:\Program
>   Files\Android\platform-tools\emulator\adb.exe","C:\Program
>   Files\Android\platform-tools\tools\adb.exe","C:\Program
>   Files\Android\platform-tools\tools\bin\adb.exe"]. Do you have
>   Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Program
>   Files\Android\platform-tools'?
>
> Assertion failed
>   C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py:656:
>   ResourceWarning: unclosed 
>   outcome.errors.clear() ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the
>   object allocation traceback
>
> Ran 1 test in 2.139s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Assertion failed
>
> Assertion failed

I am using pycharm. When I run the code I see some error log, but when I run it  from cmd, there is nothing.

[image]

And here the main part of Appium log:

```
>     Android >= 6, since UIAutomator1 framework is not maintained anymore by the OS vendor.
>         [Appium] Appium v1.13.0 creating new AndroidDriver (v4.15.1) session
>         [Appium] Capabilities:
>         [Appium]   platformName: Android
>         [Appium]   platformVersion: 6.0
>         [Appium]   deviceName: S6S5IN3G
>         [Appium]   noReset: true
>         [Appium]   appPackage: com.instagram
>         [Appium]   appActivity: com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity
>         [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"platformName":"Android","... were
> provided
>         [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa...
>         [BaseDriver] Capability 'noReset' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
>         [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 786ec1a0-280c-4573-a917-18df120f0629
>         [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
>         [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
>         [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1566428435932 (01:00:35 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)))
>         [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in ["C:\\Program
> Files\\Android\\platform-tools\\platform-tools\\adb.exe","C:\\Program
> Files\\Android\\platform-tools\\emulator\\adb.exe","C:\\Program
> Files\\Android\\platform-tools\\tools\\adb.exe","C:\\Program
> Files\\Android\\platform-tools\\tools\\bin\\adb.exe"]. Do you have
> Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Program
> Files\Android\platform-tools'?
>         [W3C]     at ADB. (C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\system-calls.js:106:11)
>         [W3C]     at Generator.next ()
>         [W3C]     at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
>         [W3C]     at _next (C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
>         [W3C]     at run (C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:75:22)
>         [W3C]     at C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:92:30
>         [W3C]     at flush (C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\_microtask.js:18:9)
>         [W3C]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>         [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 49 ms - 1544
>         [HTTP]
```

Can anyone suggest me some solutions please?

THank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have `adb.exe` in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

I would recommend going for the following setup:

1. Create `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable pointing to your Android SDK installation
2. Create `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to your JDK installation
3. Create `PATH` environment variable like:

   ```
   %ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
   ```

   [image]
4. That should be sufficient to successfully launch your Python Appium test

You can always use [appium-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor) tool in order to check the integrity of your Appium pre-requisites installation.

More information:

- [Appium Getting Started](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/)
- [Appium - Code Examples - Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Python)

Comment: Thank you so much @Dmitri for this great answer. It is very clear and abviously fixed this issue. I am now facing "Could not find 'aapt.exe'" :-). I will start new investigation about that. THanks for your time.